# 2D Vector pointer as member of class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

I am new to c++. 
I am trying to make a class which consist of 2d vector pointer. I am creating an object that takes a 2D vector as an argument. I am trying to reference this 2D vector using pointer.This compiles just fine, but I get a segmentation fault whilst execution.
I am attaching my code here. Please do help!

```
# include <iostream>
# include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Vectorref {
        vector<vector<float> >  *vptr; // pointer to 2D vector

    public:
        Vectorref(vector<vector<float> >);
        double getval(int,int);
};

Vectorref::Vectorref(vector<vector<float> > v)
{
    vptr = &v;
}

double Vectorref::getval(int r, int c)
{
    return (*vptr)[r][c];
}

int main(){
    vector<vector<float> > A (3,vector<float>(3,2.0));

    Vectorref B(A);

    for(int i=0; i<3 ;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            cout << B.getval(i,j) << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vptr = &v;` - `v` is an automatic variable; a *copy* of the passed argument. You're saving the address of an automatic variable that will cease to exist the moment the constructor exits scope.

Comment: @WhozCraig what should i do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `v` as a reference instead of copying.

```
Vectorref(vector<vector<float> >&);
Vectorref::Vectorref(vector<vector<float> >& v)
```

You **MUST** make sure that your `vector<vector<float>>` outlives your `Vectorref`, otherwise you'll get segmentation fault, again.

Your `getval` function should return `float` and not `double`.

Comment: I know its pretty basic question, But I wanted to ask that in this code, only `p` vector is occupying memory, right? Pointing and referencing are not creating any copy that will occupy memory?

Comment: From your original example. The variable `vector<vector<float> > A` will occupy the most memory. The other variable `Vectorref B` will only require `sizeof(vector<vector<float>>*) == sizeof(size_t)` bytes, which on a 64-bit machine is 8 bytes.